# Live video or voice chat with experts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

It would be good to have live video or voice chat on Stack Exchange sites. I think it would then be easier to define our problems through voice communication rather than typing.

I find it is difficult to post comments sometimes, it would be better for me if it was more flexible by being able to embed videos by pasting a link as it is done in Facebook, and other social networks.

Comment: Whilst we're imitating other social networks, can we change our profiles to be like a Timeline as well, and have the ability to tag other users in photos?

Comment: well this is my first suggestion,hope for the good one in the future.

Comment: @Matt *You've got tagged by Bobby as author of this Visual Basic Script-Code*.

Comment: @use, AKA ksa... Just to let you know, [downvotes work slighly differently here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Lix thanx for the information

Comment: Then why not use chat?

Answer (score 8):

This would require both parties to be online at the same time (and to change out of their pajamas ;)).

One of the great things about the SE sites is that you can get answers at any time of the day.  You don't know *who* the help is going to come from and you don't know *when* either.  It could be in a matter of seconds and it could be hours or even days later.

I **strongly** object to your suggestion.  If you feel it is difficult to explain yourself then there are always the [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) to allow you to explain yourself without filling your post with "noise" trying to *explain* the issue rather than trying to *solve* it.

Another point to note here is the language barriers that we all encounter on a day-to-day basis on the sites.  Often, the OP does not speak English fluently.  They can still post questions with some simplistic English and people will come along and fix gramatical and spelling errors - this would be impossible in a video/voice chat.  IMO the language barrier would be much more prominent.   So, until someone discovers how to successfully breed a [babel fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_fish_(The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)#Babel_fish) in captivity, this feature request might not be the best way to go.

---

Can you imagine a video/voice chat with [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) about [parsing HTML with regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/558021)

Or listening to Shog9 deny your feature request (in detail) on Skype? ;)

Comment: `...and to change out of their pajamas...` Very optimistic assuming that people *at least* wear pajamas. ;)

Comment: now now @kob, present company excepted, of course ;)

Comment: Or have a nice live-chat with Jeff filing a pluralization bug.

Comment: @kob - On the plus side - detecting sock puppetry might not be as difficult :P

Comment: I can already see questions asked by *real* sockpuppets. ;P

Comment: @kob - [me too ;P](http://i.imgur.com/W8QXM.png)

Answer (score 7):

No thanks.

This is extremely ineffective for several reasons:

- People do not have the time to go through a live-chat with someone. We have either limited time or are at work and trying to bridge a 5 minute gap.
- We'd lose valuable information in the video-chat, it would require us to write a complete transcript.
- Speech-barrier would even be higher then it is at the moment.
- Even if those videos would get saved, they're not searchable and they're not useful for research f.e. from work.

The (text only) chat already does exist, though.

Comment: Also, how would the community edit a video to improve it?

Comment: @vascogotlost With something [like this of course](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIEsTLYBlKM)...ah, you mean practically? ;)

Comment: Dammit! Forgot about the Unicorns.

Answer (score 4):

Helping people one at a time doesn't scale.  The whole point of Stack Overflow is to build up a searchable repository of programming information, not to provide a free support line.  Yes, having live support from some of the top users at Stack Overflow would be great for most of us, but it wouldn't be an effective use of their time.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that you can't explain your question on text then what is the possiblity that you are able to explain it on video chat?

The next request you will want is to set meeting with every poster personaly to ask you question.But things can't be like as your needs. Use the available resource fully, this requirement of your will not help but will make the SE work more complicated.

Because in this site there are so many professionals which didnot have sapperate time for every poster's question for video chat. They can easily give you answers on text and its not a tough task to write, because nobody's is here for spoon-feeding.

Comment: all I want is a phone number to call so I can speak to a live agent. Some people like the site but do not totally understand it due to reading comprehension, so is it wrong to ask for help when you do not understand...btw I can feed my self and with a fork too....sarcasm was uncalled for so I thought I"d just return the favor....never ask anyone to spoon feed me think you